# Unable to customize Samsung internet browser dark mode \ night mode

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, samsung-browser

My website looks broken on samsung browser dark mode.
i tried everything :
`@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {}` - wont mattter what style i add here it wont chang anything on samsung browser.
also tried this -

```
:root {
  color-scheme: light;
}
```

- didnt affect anything, website stays on darkmode style.
  Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, I also found the same behavior in samsung browser. It is also not working with the javascript code _window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches_ .